# Rails - omniauth gem respond with js instead html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

Using Rails 4.2 and [omniauth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth) gem. I am trying to respond with javascript from the `create` action in the `IdentitiesController` but I have a 406 Error.

view:

```
link_to "connect", "/auth/linkedin"
```

When the user click on the "connect" link the authentication with Linkedin works fine and in in the controller action there are no problem:

```
routes.rb
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'identities#create'

class IdentitiesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    pp env["omniauth.auth"] #ok it works
    #... some other code ...
  end
end
```

Linkedin respont to me in HMTL format:

```
Processing by IdentitiesController#create as HTML
```

The problem is I need to process that response as js. I have tried many solutions but nobody works for me. I have always the 406 error.